# how to update a document that is a reference for creating a another document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

updating a document that is a reference to create another document.

I have to schemas: Teacher and Class.
when I'm creating a new Class I need a teacher in order for me to create a new Class and my Teacher schema has a classes property. Right now I can already create a new class.
My problem is I want to update the teacher that is used to create a new Class and store the created class to the classes property of the teacher.

here are my schemas:

//Class Schema//

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const classSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     name: { type: String, required: true },
     subject: { type: String, required: true },
     teacher: { 
               type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
               ref: 'Teacher', 
               required: true 
     }, 
     students: []
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Class', classSchema);
```

//Teacher Schema//

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const teacherSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     email: { 
         type: String, 
         required: true, 
         unique: true,
         match: /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
     },
        password: { type: String, required: true },
        classes: [
            { 
              type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
              ref: 'Class', 
            },
       ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Teacher', teacherSchema);
```

//this my controller for creating a new Class//

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Class = require('../models/class');
const Teacher = require('../models/teacher');

exports.create_class = (req, res, next) => {
    Teacher.findById(req.body.teacherId)
        .then(teacher => {
            if (!teacher) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    message: 'Teacher not found'
                });
            }
            const _class = new Class({
                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                name: req.body.name,
                subject: req.body.subject,
                teacher: req.body.teacherId
            });
            return _class
                .save()

        })
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.status(201).json({
                message: 'Class Created',
                createdClass: {
                    _id: result._id,
                    name: result.name,
                    subject: result.subject,
                    teacher: result.teacher
                },
                req: {
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://localhost:3001/classes/' + result._id
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
}
```

I hope someone can help me. thank you in advance.

Comment: I think the problem is you are creating a circular dependency. Class has a teacher and teacher has classes. This is not good design since when you need to create both, you get a mess of code as you are trying to do now. What comes first, chicken or egg? Structure it hierarchically. Don't put classes under teachers. Rather, each class should have a teacherId. It then becomes easy to change the teacher assigned a class. You only need to change it in one collection. Then you can make a query on classes and also get the teacher through an aggregate query. I

Comment: @Emmanuel N K thank you sir for your answer..
I just want a clarification.
So what are you trying to say sir is I need to remove the classes inside my Teacher schema.?

Comment: yes. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an answer to your specific issue (there is an answer) but I think a bigger problem is your database design. You will run into problems of having to update two collections each time you create a class. If you want ot keep track of each class a teacher is assigned to, you just need to use the classes collection. You don't need to keep an array of classes for each teacher. You just need to insert a teacherId with each class created. Then you query that collection when you need to know what classes a teacher has:

```
// class schema:
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const classSchema = mongoose.Schema({
         _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         name: { type: String, required: true },
         subject: { type: String, required: true },
         teacher: { 
                   type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
                   ref: 'Teacher', 
                   required: true 
         }, 
         students: []
    });
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Class', classSchema);
```

and Teachers collection:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const teacherSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     email: { 
         type: String, 
         required: true, 
         unique: true,
         match: /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
     },
        password: { type: String, required: true },
    // teacher doesn't need classes. all the info you need is in classes
    // if you want to know what class a teacher teaches, just query classes
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Teacher', teacherSchema);
```

and finally (I've changed the fundamental of it)

```
exports.create_class = (req, res, next) => {
    const {teacherId, subject } = req.body
    // query class collection for both teacher AND class
    // you have to write this function findClassByTeacher
    // to query Class collection for subject AND teacher
    Class.findClassByTeacher({ teacherId, subject }) 
        .then(class => {
            if (!class) {
                // if no class is found by this teacher create a new class
                const _class = new Class({
                    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                    name: req.body.name,
                    subject: req.body.subject,
                    teacher: req.body.teacherId
                });

                return _class.save()
            }
            return undefined
        })
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            // check for result === undefined (class already exists)
            // return res 'class already exists'
            res.status(201).json({
                message: 'Class Created',
                createdClass: {
                    _id: result._id,
                    name: result.name,
                    subject: result.subject,
                    teacher: result.teacher
                },
                req: {
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://localhost:3001/classes/' + result._id
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
}
```

This is mostly untested so don't just use this code. the important thing is the principal behind modelling your schema. You want to use one-to-many relationships. for example, User has many posts, Post has many comments, Comments have many Likes etc. You don't *have to* design it this way with NoSQL, you can do what you have (or you're trying to achieve) but in my experience this way is so much more manageable, especially for long term scaling (if you ever need to do db migrations, complex queries on the db etc).

In your case, Teacher and Students have many Classes. You need to assess what data your app accesses frequently and model around that.

Check this out the various design patterns: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models/

I'd give that a good read and based on what you do, choose the best model for your collection.

Comment: Sir.. thank you for your response..

I have another and maybe my final question Lol.

How I can get all the classes using a specific teacherId,
Let's say a one teacher is used to create a many classes.